# Spaghetti plots in R

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
   PatientID Visit  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4 Var5
1        ID1     0 42.28  4.57 22.56  4.36 8.87
2        ID1     1 55.60  6.34  3.74  3.76 6.96
3        ID1     2 69.45 11.18 20.69  2.15 8.34
4        ID2     0 58.78  7.81  6.57  1.19 7.31
5        ID2     1 10.33 38.27  0.48 14.41   NA
6        ID2     2 69.45 11.18 20.69  2.15 8.34
7        ID3     0 69.16  6.17  8.98  1.91 6.12
8        ID3     1 86.02 19.62  4.18  2.36 4.17
9        ID3     2 69.45 11.18 20.69  2.15 8.34
10       ID4     0 94.05 26.75  2.89  2.92 2.17
11       ID4     1 48.66 14.38  4.96  1.13 4.78
12       ID4     2 69.45 11.18 20.69  2.15 8.34
```

I actually have about 60 var in total, so here I am just showing a sample. I need to calculate in R the mean for each variable at each visit for all individuals and then create a spaghetti plot with 60 lines (each corresponding to the mean values at each visit for each variable to check if there is a change over time, i.e. visit). I also need to colour the lines for specific variables, for example var 1 and var 4, in red.

I usually create spaghetti plots with the following code, but in this case I might need to create a loop for calculating the means?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

tspag = ggplot(all.data, aes(x=Visit, y=Mean_values)) + 
  geom_line() + guides(colour=FALSE) + xlab("Days after") +
  ylab("Mean plot") + theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

spag = tspag + aes(colour = factor(XXXX))
spag
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you already tried anything to calculate the means? How do you usually do that?

Comment: what does data table and plyr have to do with this code? where are your attempts to get the means

Answer (score 0):

You need a little data wrangling to get your means. Here I'll use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
all.data <- dat %>% group_by(Visit) %>%
                    summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), -PatientID) %>%
                    gather(variable, val, -Visit)
```

So, we grouped by visit, took the mean of every column (except patientID), then reshaped the data to long format using gather.

Now you can plot it. i'll leave off all your themes - they can be easily added back:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(all.data, aes(x = Visit, y = val, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I now have the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want means of each `Var-n`, for each visit, averaged over all the patients, here's a solution that uses ggplot to summarize your data.

```
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
library(ggplot2)
gg.df <- melt(df, id=1:2)
ggplot(gg.df, aes(x=Visit, y=value, color=variable))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(gg.df$Visit))
```

[image]